# Convert string imported from JSON to table in Lua

Tags: json, lua

I want to convert the string `"balm"` to a table. Balm was imported from a JSON File using dkjson

```
balm =
{
    "a": "test"
    "b" : { "test1":1, "test2":2, "test3":3},
    "c" : { "test4: 4, "test5": "/path/to/folder"}
}
```

Comment: dkjson has a `decode` method (so just `balm = json.decode(balm)`), but you should probably read through the documentation a bit more before asking on SO :c
In this case it's the second method outlined in the README: https://github.com/LuaDist/dkjson/blob/master/readme.txt#L71

Comment: And: ```balm``` is json (Not a valid Lua table) - ```balm = [[{ "a" : "test" }]]``` is a string for Lua.

Comment: It gets stored as a string. im trying to get it as a nested table

Answer (score 0):

Like in the comment wrote, it is easy, if you follow the datatype rules.
Example using NeoVIM...
[image: Lua and nvim converting json string]
...it will output "test" under the nvim status line.